# use the bundle in more activities?

Tags: android

I have main activity and two another activities(second and third). I create a bundle in main activity and intent like this`Intent intent = new Intent(this,second.class);` and I want to use get extras in third activity. like `bundle comes = getIntent().getExtras();`. is it possible or why not?

Comment: If you are asking if it is possible to use an Intent with extra's for one activity. And intent with bundle for another one. Then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

> and I want to use get extras in third activity. like bundle comes =
>   getIntent().getExtras();. is it possible or why not?

You are able to **getExtras()** only from Intent that will start your third Activity. So in other words if your MainActivity starts third Activity you are able to retrieve data in third Activity if you'll append them into intent that starts third Activity:

```
// this is calling from MainActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Third.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

If MainActivity doesn't start third Activity, you are not able to do it. But you're able retrieve data in third Activity from your second Activity (again here you have to append data to Intent):

```
// this is calling from SecondActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Third.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Shared Preferences" to store and access some data, anytime you wish.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html